# Mopub, Admob, millennial

Tags: java, android, admob, mopub

I'm new to developing apps with ads. I would like to know how would i integrate the admob, millennial, mopub in my application. Currently I'm able to show the mopub test ads but I don't know how to display the other ads from admob and millennial. What I want to do is when the ads of Mopub finish loading it will then load my millennial ads then my admob. Then will repeat again.

Thanks.

Hope to hear from you guys soon.

Comment: Google will help you a lot faster that SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the below Links which will guide you for integrating Mopub,admob,millennial

1) Integrate [millennial](http://docs.millennialmedia.com/android-SDK/)
2) [Integrating](http://manijshrestha.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/integrating-admob-in-your-android-app-and-make-money/) [Admob](http://www.buzztouch.com/files/howtos/New%20Admob%20integration%20for%20Android.pdf)
3) Integrate [Mopub](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Getting-Started)